# how can I ban or keep on hold a topic in mosquitto broker?

Tags: mosquitto

I need to block or delete the topic from mosquitto broker.

Is there any method to delete the topic from the broker ?

Answer (score 0):

As asked your question doesn't make sense. Topics don't really exist in the broker, what exists is a list of topic patterns that each client is subscribed to. The broker matches the topic field on incoming published messages against each clients set of patterns (because it's possible to subscribe to wildcard topics) and if it matches then it delivers the message to that client.

The another possible interpretation of your question is that you want to remove a retained message. Retained messages are held by the broker and delivered to every client that subscribes to a matching pattern when they subscribe. To do this you need to publish a message with a null payload and the retained bit set to the matching topic. With `mosquitto_pub` you do that as follows:

```
mosquitto_pub -t foo/bar -r -n
```

- `-t` sets the topic
- `-r` sets the retained bit
- `-n` sets a null payload

If you mean how do you stop users from publishing to or subscribing to topics then you need to look at the `acl_file` section of the mosquitto.conf man [page](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html)